# Fazer download de imagem em link com parêntesis PHP

Tags: php, imagem, url, download

então estou tentando fazer download de uma imagem atraves de uma url...
já identifiquei o problema...
exemplo:

```
    <?php
$imgurl = 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTA2MTk3NzI5Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNzU2MzYyNzE@._V1_SX300.jpg';
if( !@copy( $imgurl, './teste.jpg' ) ) {
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
```

isso funciona... agora se eu tento com essa url:
http://www.fatisa.com.br/imoveis/docs/imoveis/terreno (1).jpg
da erro de link...

Comment: a url que está a testar é exatamente essa incluindo o espaço ?

Comment: isto...ja tentei substituir espaços e os parentesis mas não vai...

Comment: Como assim, substituiu pelo que ?

Answer (score 5):

O problema é o espaço no nome da foto. Para resolver pode usar um `rawurlencode()` na parte do nome.

```
copy('http://fatisa.com.br/imoveis/docs/imoveis/'.rawurlencode('terreno (1).jpg'), './teste.jpg');
```

Rodei o comando e salvou a foto sem problema.